# Including application crons

Tags: users, cron

I have 5 web applications. The directory structure is similar to following:

```
/var
   `-  /www
            `- /domains
                      `-  /domain1
                                 `- /public_html
                                               `- /crontabs
                                                        `- /crons
                      `-  /domain2
                                 `- /public_html
                                               `- /crontabs
                                                        `- /crons
                      `-  /domain3
                                 `- /public_html
                                               `- /crontabs
                                                        `- /crons
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
                               .
```

Each application has its own list of crons [and these files contain valid, crontab -e like, syntax]. At the moment as this is a test and isolated server so all applications run under the same user. I know about crons, /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.interval (interval = hourly|daily|weekly), /var/spool/crontabs/.

My question: is there an alternate to /etc/cron.d but user specific where i could just symlink these crons and they would be executed? I would prefer such a solution because these crons get updated at times from developers.

On #ubuntu ikonia suggested to google on how could one include crons, i did and couldn't find such a solution. If there could be place where i could do:

```
include /var/www/domains/*/public_html/crontabs/crons
```

that would be totally awesome.

[EDIT]
I am open to changing the crons files a little.

Answer (score 4):

**Root-level** crontabs can be symlinked into /etc/cron.d/ . Everything in that folder is executed as root. It's possible for a root-level crontab entry to be executed as user-level, but that's a workaround and beyond the scope of the question. An example of such a symlink:

```
# ln -s /path/to/crontab /etc/cron.d/
```

**User-level** crontabs cannot be created by symlink or any kind of direct file management - crontab management is specifically designed to prevent users from doing that. All user-level crontabs **must** be created using the 'crontab' command, so that all user-level crontabs get checked for syntax, and get spooled in the same place.

**Happily**, the 'crontab' does more than merely open an editor. The command will accept entire files. For example, for the user owning $DomainName,

```
$ crontab /var/www/$DomainName/public_html
```

So it should be quite easy to add a user-level crontab to the webapp startup script.

**In Ubuntu 16.04 and newer**, cron jobs are slowly being replaced by  systemd timers, but that's also beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

On my web server, I give every virtual server a own linux user. Every linux user has its own crontab.